# table td width and float

Tags: html, html-table

Good evening!
I'm doing this thing:

```
<div id="infoGen" align="center">
    <table id="tabInfoGen">
        <tr>
            <td id="primacol">Nome:&nbsp;<font id="h3"><%=u.getNome()%></font><br>
                Cognome:&nbsp; <font id="h3"><%=u.getCognome()%></font><br>
                Indirizzo:&nbsp; <font id="h3"><%=u.getIndirizzo()%></font><br>
                Città:&nbsp;<font id="h3"><%=u.getCitta()%></font>
            </td>
            <td id="secondacol">Data di Nascita:&nbsp; <font
                id="h3"><%=u.getDataNascita()%></font><br> Luogo di
                Nascita:&nbsp;<font id="h3"> <%=u.getLuogoDiNascita()%></font><br>
                Telefono:&nbsp;<font id="h3"> <%=u.getTelefono()%></font><br>
                Email:&nbsp; <font id="h3"><%=u.getEmail()%></font>
            </td>
            <td id="terzacol">Username:&nbsp; <font id="h3"><%=u.getUsername()%></font>
                <br> Password:&nbsp; <font id="h3"> <%
for (int i = 0; i < u.getPassword().length(); i++)
    out.print("*");
  %>
                </font>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

with this css

```
#infoGen {
background-color: #F2F5A9;
width: 800px;
border-radius: 20px;
border: 1px solid black;
}

 #infoGen table {
width: 100%;
padding-top: 20px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
font: 16px Impact, sans-serif;
text-align: left;
 }
 td #primacol {
float: left;
margin-left: 50px;
width: 200px;
}

td #secondacol {
width: 200px;
float: left;
margin-left: 20px;
}

td #terzacol {
float: left;
margin-left: 50px;
width: 200px;
}
```

the problem is that I would like to have 3 columns with the same width but In this case I have the first column very large and the other two are small.
How can I fix this?

http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Floating table cells is really not a good idea.

Comment: @sevenseacat ok. but even if I delete float the result doesn't change. If I deete float I have the 3 columns in a stack.

Comment: Can you try to set width to 600 inside infoGen instead of 800

Comment: @AshReva nothing to do :-(

Comment: Close out your td and tr tags first

Comment: @thequerist doesn't change anithing. I've ut the jsfiddle of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS selectors are incorrect. A space infers descendent

```
/* look for id=secondacol within any TD*/
td #secondacol
```

Should be

```
/* TD that has ID=secondacol*/
td#secondacol
```

Comment: I had an error in another file css and so I had that problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have css rules like this:

```
td #primacol {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 50px;
    max-width: 200px;
}
```

When it should be like this:

```
td#primacol {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 50px;
    max-width: 200px;
}
```

Note the space removed between the TD and the ID.

Not related but you can't have multiple IDs that are the same. Use a class instead. Also using the FONT tag is a bit 15 years ago.

Additionally you shouldn't be using tables for this layout as tables are meant to be only for tabular date.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `max-width`:

```
td#primacol {
    margin-left: 50px;
    max-width: 200px;
}

td#secondacol {
    max-width: 200px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

td#terzacol {
    margin-left: 50px;
    max-width: 200px;
}
```